# Appending to / concatenating multiple strings in one call in PHP?

Tags: php, shortcut

I know you can assign to multiple variables in one call like so:

```
$varOne = $varTwo = "some value";
```

But is there a way append to multiple variables (strings) in one call?

Clearly this is incorrect syntax, but I was thinking something like this:

```
$varOne = "he's ";
$varTwo = "she's ";
$varOne, $varTwo .= "insane";

echo $varOne; // Outputs "he's insane"
echo $varTwo; // Outputs "she's insane"
```

Comment: S'pose you could put var(One|Two) in an array instead then use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to concatenate  'in one call' like this in php outside making your own function and calling it.  Appending operators work on only one variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, not really. At best, you could use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) like so:

```
 foreach (array('varOne', 'varTwo') as $var) {
     $$var .= 'insane';
 }
```

Variable variables are a maintenance headache though, and by maintenance headache, I mean a kitten gets killed each time you use the construct, so beware.

Comment: I'd +1, but merely allowing others to know of varvar's existence makes me want to -MAX_INT instead...

Comment: @MarcB Oh, believe me, I totally agree.